# How to make Row data type in MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb

I would like to use [SQLData](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=interface-sqldata-examples) (something like that) to store some data. But I cant find suitable statment to create that thing. Currently tried using

```
CREATE ROW TYPE `myType` (`name` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no user-defined/composite types support in MariaDB or MySQL:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/does-mariadb-support-user-defined-types-udts/

SQL Server or PostgreSQL would be a better fit for that.